# How do I transpose my current range?

Tags: excel, transpose, vba

How do I transpose the output in the code below?

```
Dim lastRow As Range, rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Worksheets(1).Range("I80:I83")
Set lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
lastRow.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, rng1.Columns.Count) = rng1.Value
```

Comment: It depends on the size of your range. For small size range, you can try `Application.Transpose(yourrangehere)`.

Comment: @L42 So it would be Application.Transpose(rng1.value)?

Comment: With or without `.Value`, it is the default property anyway.

Comment: @L42 Hmmmm. With or without `.Value` The code `Application.Transpose(rng1)` only copies I81 & doesn't transpose either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. Consider the following example: (can't fit to comment)

```
With Sheet1 '/* or what ever your sheet object is */
    .Range("A1") = 1
    .Range("A2") = 2
    .Range("A3") = 3

    .Range("C1:E1") = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1:A3"))
End With
```

Applying to your code:

```
Dim lastRow As Range, rng1 As Range

With Thisworkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set rng1 = .Range("I80:I83")
    Set lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    lastrow.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Columns.Count, rng1.Rows.Count) = rng1.Value
End With
```

Comment: But I'm not using With in my code
`lastRow.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, rng1.Columns.Count) = Application.Transpose(rng1)` Is this how I should incorporate `Application.Transpose` to my code?

Comment: @Tyler Yes. But make sure you have the correct destination range. Make sure that your `lastrow` contains the correct range.

Comment: But for some reason applying `application.transpose` produces the first cell of its range in all its output (E.g. I80 value is applied over to I81 - I83 & not transpose at all either)

Comment: @Tyler Ah, you didn't transpose the destination. See my edit applying the logic to your code.

Comment: I see. The transpose works now but the value of I80 is applied throughout the range